# Flutter (Dart): List<Iterable>.contains() always giving a false even when the string is present in list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, contains, string-comparison

I am trying to check if a string exists in a list of strings or not. Am using `.contains` method to evaluate this. However, this is always giving me a false, even when the string is present in the list. Check the below code and the print logs

I have already tried the traditional for loop to check via `==` operator. that as well didn't work.

```
print("atText -- ");
print(atText);

print("tagStrings -- ");
print(tagStrings);

print("atText.runtimeType -- ");
print(atText.runtimeType);

print("tagStrings.runtimeType -- ");
print(tagStrings.runtimeType);

print("tagStrings[0].runtimeType -- ");
print(tagStrings[0].runtimeType);

print("tagStrings.contains(atText) -- ");
print(tagStrings.contains(atText));
```

Output Log:

```
I/flutter (32648): atText --
I/flutter (32648): @alkjsdhf-lkasdfjklasfdh-kajsdhf-lajksdhf-klsjdafh-lkasdfhkasd-f
I/flutter (32648): tagStrings --
I/flutter (32648): [@alkjsdhf-lkasdfjklasfdh-kajsdhf-lajksdhf-klsjdafh-lkasdfhkasd-f]
I/flutter (32648): atText.runtimeType --
I/flutter (32648): String
I/flutter (32648): tagStrings.runtimeType --
I/flutter (32648): List<String>
I/flutter (32648): tagStrings[0].runtimeType --
I/flutter (32648): String
I/flutter (32648): tagStrings.contains(atText) --
I/flutter (32648): false
```

The last line `tagStrings.contains(atText)` should have given me `true`

Comment: I ran the code in dartpad and it works fine :   final s = "@alkjsdhf-lkasdfjklasfdh-kajsdhf-lajksdhf-klsjdafh-lkasdfhkasd-f";
  final s2  =["@alkjsdhf-lkasdfjklasfdh-kajsdhf-lajksdhf-klsjdafh-lkasdfhkasd-f"];
  print(s);
  print("\n");
  print(s2);
  print("Contain: ${s2.contains(s)}");

Comment: The code looks like it should work. Try printing the `codeUnits` of both `atText` and `tagStrings[0]` and see if they agree. You might have an invisible character in one of the strings.